# How would you "debounce" log messages using Serilog

Tags: serilog

Context: We have an architecture that includes polling, which pollutes the logs with statements at a high rate.

My dream would be that those statements can be collected for a certain period of time, and then logged in a single "summary" message like "In the last 5 minutes the following messages was logged n times."

How would you approach that?

Thanks